# Simple question how to limit logging out

Tags: password, settings, logout

Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2LTS logs out automatically after inactivity of about 5 minutes. I can't find the setting for this and would like to change the value to, say, 20-30 minutes of inactivity. This is a constant aggravation to me because I use a difficult password.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the dock is the box of squares. Select it and then go to the settings you want to change.

Comment: I guess I have a buggy install. I know your way works in straight Ubuntu 20.04 but there is a separate category "Settings" in the main menu in Studio -- I changed the Power settings to never blank out but what setting limits logout?

Answer (score 0):

open setting by pressing start button and searching or by clicking the box of squares u might need to scroll down afterwards go into power and turn off black screen and everything else this will solve your problem if it dosent let me know

Comment: I'm sorry, I had already changed all power settings to never blank screes and set everything for "go to sleep" to "never." This is a buggy install because of installation with dial-up speed using USB tethering for internet, I had thought it was a problem with a setting but I see that it is not. Thanks everyone for your prompt help.

Comment: You are welcome
can you mark my question helpfull.Thanks